# Now found on other planets!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Another very simple riddle since my other puzzle still hasn't been solved.

> A single breath, that's all I need to kill you,
> Given properly, and I will refresh you.
>
> Unable to avoid me, for life is what I provide,
> Always am around you, except where it's dried.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Water

A single breath, that's all I need to kill you,

> Brething in water could kill you

Given properly, and I will refresh you.

> If drunk, water is refreshing

Unable to avoid me, for life is what I provide,

> Water covers 71% of the Earth's surface and is a major constituent of many living organisms

Always am around you, except where it's dried.

> If there is not water it won't be wet, hence dry.

Now found on other planets!

> Water is thought to exist as liquid beneath the surface of some planetary bodies.

Secret clue (thanks @Mohirl)

> The initial letters of each line spells 'AGUA', the Spanish word for water.

Comment: I figured this one would be very quick. If you finish up the explanations, I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: If you add in how it ties to the title and the secret clue, that'd be great as well :D

Comment: The secret clue is rot13(Nthn, sebz gur vavgvnyf bs rnpu yvar)

Comment: You got them all.

Comment: The title says "not found on other planets". Is this accurate? I thought they found water on Mars

Comment: @DEEM It says 'Now found...'